# fit element to available height css

Tags: html, css, layout, position

i have two elements in the body, a div and iframe. the div header have fixed height(100px) so, i want that the iframe fit to all rest of height. The body can't show the scroll bars but iframe must have scrollbars.

[Here an example.](http://jsbin.com/exeyev/1/edit)

Thak you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for this:

```
.content{
  height:    -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  height:         calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

- [**Example**](http://jsbin.com/exeyev/3/)
- [**Browser Compatibility**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) (basically IE9+)

Comment: Never would have thought of that, I need to get reacquainted with the new CSS3 properties.

Comment: is there a way for olds browsers?

Comment: @iLevi There might be a polyfill around, but I don't know of it.

Comment: could be used negative margins, or something like that for get this??

Comment: well, while i look for another solution, i will use Sirko solution. Thanks Sirko.

Comment: Consists in put a div and put into the content. See in http://jsbin.com/exeyev/6/edit